# When twitter goes down, elements on my site breaks as well. How to prevent this?

Tags: twitter

As we know [Twitter.com was down](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/06/todays-turbulence-explained.html) in yesterday(2012/07/26) some period of time. In that time my website home page somewhat unresponsive. The homepage was trying to load the twitter feed and failing, and thus other page elements in my site appears broken, like a jquery slider has trouble loading correctly, because its trying to load the twitter API.

Hove to fix this to homepage  ignore twitter feed if the site notices that it is down, and displaying a short error notice in place of the feed?

I am using following customize twitter widget ([got from here](http://www.nouveller.com/css/get-yourself-a-great-looking-custom-twitter-badge/)) to show latest 2 twitts in Home page.

```
<div id='twitter_div'>                        
<ul id='twitter_update_list'>       
</ul>                             
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// to filter @replies in twitter feed
    function filterCallback( twitter_json )
        { var result = [];for(var index in twitter_json) 
        { if(twitter_json[index].in_reply_to_user_id == null) {result[result.length] = twitter_json[index]; }
        if( result.length==2 ) break;}twitterCallback2(result); }
    </script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/DUOBoots.json?callback=filterCallback&amp;count=10'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delay load your twitter feed. The rest of your page will load right away and if/when twitter goes down it won't block the rest of your page. It's good practice to do this anyway.

See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3369 for a discussion with some examples on using jquery to do this.